# Recycler View with Collapsing toolbar on scroll up toolbar does not collapse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity with a FrameLayout in which i add or replace several fragments. That activity uses CollapsingToolbarLayout.

In the first scenario I add a fragment with a NestedScrollView, a LinearLayout, a CardView and TextViews. Everything works fine, the scrolling and collapse / expand of toolbar.

In the second scenario, i add a fragment to the FrameLayout with SwipeRefreshLayout and a RecyclerView but the problem is when i scroll up the toolbar does not collapse.

In this video you can see the problem: [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7fxM1pSrqw)

**The activity layout:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

     ................

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/printerModels"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    style="@style/FabStyle"/>
```

**First scenario fragment layout:**

```
<android:android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/model_detail_card_view_margin">

            ..........
            ..........
            //Several textviews here
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>

</android:android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Second scenario layout:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_users"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_progress"
        />

    <include
        layout="@layout/view_retry"
        />

    <!--</LinearLayout>-->

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable nested scrolling for RecyclerView in your xml

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your coordinate layout:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

             ................

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 //This  <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/printerModels"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            style="@style/FabStyle"/>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<android:android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

 <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

            </FrameLayout>

</android:android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Nothing was changed

Comment: Try setting it to tecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

Comment: Put your frame layout in nested scroll view and replace your fragment there and create different fragment layout for first scenario with linear layout as parent

Comment: If i put NestedScrollView the onBindViewHolder is never called and the recycler view is not populated with data

Comment: Their is not no relation between onBindViewHolder and nestedScollview....recycle view will be in fragmnet which attach to the framelayout inside nestedView which is included in your collapsing layout

Comment: I made it work by adding fillViewPort true to the NestedScrollView. The scrolling up makes the toolbar collapse although scrolling down to the end of the RecyclerView doesnt work.

Comment: No still cant scroll to the bottom of the list. I can only scroll until the Toolbar is fully collapsed